# Help me with alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Anyone can help me write a latex for this?
[image]

Except there should be no space between the letters because they are one word (ex. no space between d,e,and f).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)

Comment: Although there is already an answer:  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks rather strange, but if you wish...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Here are some examples: \begin{minipage}[t]{52mm}
a\hfill = \hfill b\hfill ${}=1$ 

c\hfill= \hfill def\hfill =\hfill g \hfill ${}=2$

h\hfill = \hfill ijkl \hfill = \hfill mn \hfill ${}=3$

o \hfill = \hfill p \hfill = \hfill  qr \hfill = \hfill stuv \hfill = \hfill wxy \hfill ${}=4$
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I can assume from your example, that there should be equal spacing around equal signs in a line, with an exception of the final one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But how do I make 'Here are some examples:' to be on the first line, not on the middle?

Comment: @user55882 Oh, it is also important? Please see the corrected version (the option `t` as top in minipage). I hope that changing the picture is not necessary.

Comment: dziękuję! I appreciate your help

Comment: @user55882 O! Czyżby Polak? (I have asked OP, if (s)he is a Pole).

Comment: No, just a beginner in Polish lol.

Answer (score 4):

The equals signs make me suspect this is math; in this case here's a solution with a simple syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{\thickmuskip=1\thickmuskip plus 1fill\relax}c}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{s@{}>{{}}l}
a = b &=1 \\
c = def = g &=2 \\
h = ijkl = mn &=3 \\
o = p = qr = stuv = wxy &=4
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]